# End Kernel panic -not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(2,0)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I created a partiton on my hard drive (160GB) and then made used Universal USB Installer to make it bootable for Ubuntu 16.04. So I restarted my PC and displayed ubuntu install options. Then I clicked on install ubuntu and gives the error End Kernel panic -not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(2,0).
I also tried to boot from first hard drive but it also failed. So I'm stuck at the ubuntu install options. 
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your usb file system should be fat32 instead of ntfs.
Format your usb with fat32.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)